# C# WPF popup doesn't appear

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I'm fairly new at coding and i'm struggling with a popup that doesn't appear at runtime.

I'm trying to make an autocomplete/suggestion popup list but i can't seem to be able to make it work.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="editorInputColumn"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Ajouter (séparateur ';') :">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource FontColor}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>     
    <Grid x:Name="popupEditorGrid" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible">
        <Popup Placement="Top" Visibility="Visible" StaysOpen="True"  Panel.ZIndex="1000" x:Name="EditorPopup"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=editorInputColumn}">
            <StackPanel x:Name="EditorPopupStackPanel">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource EllipseSecondary}"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
                    <TextBlock Text="test"/><!--this is just an attempt at displaying something in the popup, but even this does not appear at runtime-->
            </StackPanel>
       </Popup>
   </Grid>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" KeyUp="editorAddInput_KeyUp" x:Name="editorAddInput" >
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BoutonMarge}"/>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
private void editorAddInput_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string lastInput;

        List<string> inputList = editorAddInput.Text.ToUpper().Split(',', ';').ToList();

        if (inputList.Count != 0)
        {
            lastInput = inputList[inputList.Count - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            lastInput = editorAddInput.Text;
        }

        List<Editor> matchingEditorsList = new List<Editor>();

        EditorPopupStackPanel.Children.Clear();


        foreach(Editor editor in localEditorsList)//look up among all known names
        {
            if(editor.Name.StartsWith(lastInput))
            {
                matchingEditorsList.Add(editor);
            }
        }

        if(matchingEditorsList.Count!=0)
        {
            EditorPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            foreach(Editor editor in matchingEditorsList)
            {
                EditorPopupStackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = editor.Name });         
            }
            EditorPopup.StaysOpen = true;
            EditorPopup.IsOpen = true;

        }
        else
        {
            EditorPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            EditorPopup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

The input Textbox is supposed to be able to get several names, separated by a ";", so I start by getting the last one being typed.

Funny enough, the popup does appear in Visual Studio's Conceptor view when selected, but not when running. I've tried playing with z-index with no success. Any idea on what i messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Put textbox inside grid in XAML

Comment: It already is, sorry. I didn't paste the whole code because this is part of a much larger window, but what i pasted is encapsulated in a two column grid, along with a TextBlock (wich in in column 0).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `IsOpen` property, which should be set to `true` for the popup to be displayed.